# Google chrome extension Simple REST Client

Tags: rest, google-chrome, post

I am using Google chrome extension tool [Simple REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fhjcajmcbmldlhcimfajhfbgofnpcjmb?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) to test my web services. How to call post method with multiple parameters. I searched in internet, there is no enough documentation for this app.

Example POST method

```
    @POST
     @Path("createcategory")
     @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
     @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
     public void CreateCategory(@FormParam("cname") String cname,@FormParam("cdescription") String cdescription) 
    {


     CategoriesBO category = new CategoriesBO();
     category.setCategoryName(cname);
     category.setCategoryDescription(cdescription);

     CategoriesEntityHandler handler = new CategoriesEntityHandler();
     try {
        category = handler.createCategory(category);


    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a question about how to use the Chrome Simple REST Client? Then your question is off topic here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[This link](http://programmingnotes.thinktanktheory.com/chrome-simple-rest-client/) suggested adding

```
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

in the header box and a paramlist:

```
(param1=val1&param2=val2&...)
```

in the data box, which worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For "Headers", each header needs to be on a newline:

```
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36
```

While "Data" needs to be in json-format, so something like this:

```
{"login":"USERNAME","password":"PASSWORD"}
```

using a paramlist did not work for me.